# Pandas selecting rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to select only those row which fulfill my condition.

```
options = ['apple', 'banana','cat','dog'] 
#selecting rows based on condition 
rslt_df = data[(data['Animal'] == "All") & data['Category'].isin(options)]
print(rslt_df)
```

But I am getting this error.

```
       #selecting rows based on condition
-----> rslt_df = data[(data['Animal'] == "All") & data['Category'].isin(options)]
       print(rslt_df)
       TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Comment: Did you search first? This is a very common use case. You can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas). Plus, how is your dataframe, what condition? is `All` a possible value in `Animal` column?. Elaborate please.

Comment: How working `data[(data['Animal'].values == "All") & data['Category'].isin(options)]` ?

Comment: Another idea - what is your pandas version?

Comment: my pandas version is 0.25, Thanks for answering guys now its working. @jezrael

Comment: Thanks for answering guys now its working. @MikaMajara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was in some old versions of pandas, solution is upgrade to last version and then use your original solution:

```
rslt_df = data[(data['Animal'] == "All") & data['Category'].isin(options)]
```

Comment: thanks alot @jezrael and also i have marked your post as answered.

Answer (score -1):

If you provide an example DataFrame we can check why you have TypeError. But if you have the same datatypes this should work.

```
mask = (data['Animal'] == "All") & (data['Category'].isin(options))
new_df = df.loc[mask]
```

Comment: Thnx @pesap its working. and I'll mark your post as answered.

Comment: @Ram - Yes, it working, but if remove `()` like in your original solution, then `()` are not necessary for `isin`.

Comment: @Ram - Also your problem is `TypeError: invalid type comparison` and if dont upgrade, same error